# How to make Magento 'Show out of stock products' option different per website/store view?

Tags: php, magento

I have a retail and a trade site setup in Magento (different websites and store views).

The retail site shows only in stock products, but on the trade site it needs to show out of stock products as well.

I was looking for a way to override the global admin option in the back office, or to modify the collection directly on the `.phtml` file. Possibly by loading the collection without the stock availability check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `isShowOutOfStock()` method:

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Data.php:119

```
public function isShowOutOfStock()
{
    /* New Code */
    if( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'code-of-trade-site')
        return 1;
    /* /New Code */

    return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SHOW_OUT_OF_STOCK);
}
```

P.S. This code is written assuming you have set **Display Out of Stock Products** to **No** in `System->Configuration->Inventory`.

Comment: do i only need to copy this file into 'app/code/local/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Data.php' directory, and add the new lines of code?

Comment: Yes, or you can follow this tutorial to override the Helper with your own: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: Hi Cameron Shaw. Have you been able to show out of products with the method above L. Palaiokostas suggested?

I have the same scenario and follow above instruction - but it doesn't seem to work :(

Thanks